# Combining selenium test class and tkinter

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, ui-automation

This is my first attempt at using the Tkinter plugin, I know very little past what tutorials I could find. All the answers I've seen so far put a class inside the py file that your building, I however have a plethora of tests that are already compiled into a Test class that runs many separate tests. All the tests run and no errors are encountered before trying to add to the ui.

I would like to be able to run each suite by clicking a button. My problem seems that I'm missing a step some where but not getting any errors or action when I click the button, but an error after I click and close the ui window. I should point out that importing the settings file (which contains most of the webdriver imports) does not help either. I get the same error.

Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 663, in __call__
return self.run(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 590, in run
testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'runTest'
```

My ui code:

```
import sys, os, tkinter, TESTadmin
top = tkinter.Tk()
a = TESTadmin.Test()
B = tkinter.Button(top, text= "Test Window", command=a )
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

for clarity my main test file:

```
from helpers.settings import *
from pieces import adminLogin, adminLogout, docs


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):

    # Maximize Window (remove quotes to use)
    '''sel.maximize_window()'''

    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.get("https://mywebsite.net")
    # We instantiate and start the browser

def testCases(self):# Add Tests Below
    #log in to admin side
    login = adminLogin.AdminLogin.do(self)
    #docs page
    docpage = docs.Docs.do(self)
    #log out
    logout = adminLogout.Logout.do(self)
    if G.log:
        for k in G.log.items():
            print(k)

### Uncomment to close browser after test ###   
def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it would turn out, the answer like I thought is simple.

this line :

```
def testCases(self):
```

needs to read:

```
def runTest(self):
```

after that change every thing works percectly.

My confusion is because originally when building these tests I was following the directions here -> https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
They show you to use the testCases() method, and this works! Just not for calling the class. I didn't know where to put the function let alone know that Webdriver had a built in function other than what i was using.